# Failing to understand a proof in topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I have read the following theorem:

Let $ \{ A_{j} \} $ be a family of subsets of topological space $X$ which is either an open covering or a finite closed covering of $X$. Let $H$ be a subset of $X$ and let $ H_j := A_{j} \cap H $, for each index $j$. Then $H$ is open in $X$ if $ H_j $ is open in $A_j$ for each $j$, while $H$ is closed in $X$ if $H_j$ is closed in $A_j$ for each $j$.

The following proof is provided,

Proof: Suppose that $ \{ A_j \} $ is an open covering. If $H_j$ is open in $A_j$ for each $j$ then $H_j$ is open in $X$ for each $j$ and so the union $H$ of $H_j$ is open in $X$...

I would like to stop here. My question is that, since for each $j$, the open sets in $A_j$ should be defined as exactly those sets $  A_j \cap U $ where $U$ is open in $X$. Why can't we claim immediately that $H$ is open in $ X $ if $ A_{j} \cap H $ is open in $A_j$. Moreover, how can it be claimed that if $H_j$ is open in $A_j$ for each $j$ then $H_j$ is open in $X$ for each $j$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: open in open is open. See my full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $O$ is open in $X$ and $A$ is open in $O$, $A$ is open in $X$. (open in open is open); the proof is immediate: $A$ is open in $O$ means $A = U \cap O$ for some $U$ which is open in $X$, but then $A$ is open in $X$ as the intersection of two open sets of $X$ (namely $U$ and $O$).

If you just know that $H \cap A_j$ is open in $A_j$ for some $j$ then $H$ could be non-open: e.g. $H = [1,3]$, $A_j = (0,1)$, then $H \cap A_j = (0,1)$ is open in $(0,1)$ but $H$ is not open. We need that the $A_j$ form a cover of $X$ and that $H \cap A_j$ is open for *all* $j$, to conclude that $H$ is open.
But the proof starts by noting that all sets $H \cap A_j$ are open in $X$, and $H$ is their union.

The same holds for closed in closed too, with the same proof, essentially.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks! However, why cant we just used the definition of open sets in subspace? As in the first part of my question.

Comment: @Meagain that's what I did, didn't I?

Comment: This is interesting. In this book the definition of relative topology is defined using embedding. We take the injection $ \sigma : A \rightarrow X $ and then give $A$ the topology induced by $\sigma$. The author doesn't explicitly state what this injection is but I just assumed it is the indicator function of $A$. By this I mean that the open sets of $A$ should consist exactly the inverse images of open set in $X$ under $\sigma$. Then we call this topology on $A$ as the relative topology.

Comment: So I think at least in terms of this book cases where $H$ is closed in $X$ should be excluded. Although your explanation still makes sense.

Comment: @Meagain The topology induced by $\sigma$  is just the set $\{O \cap A: O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$. Also, taking complements we see that $C$ is closed in $A$ iff $C = D \cap A$ where $D$ is some closed subset of $X$.

Comment: @Meagain $H$ open is for the open cover case, $H$ closed for the finite closed cover case. They're two separate results.

Comment: So would it be correct to think in the following sense? $ H = [1,3] $ is closed in $X$. So using the definition of induced topology we cannot directly conclude that $  A \cap H $ is open in $A$. However in this case, $H$ contains $A$, then $ A \cap H = A$ is the full set in $A$ so by definition is open and closed.

Comment: Is it possible for us to find an closed set $H$ in $X$, take the intersection $ A \cap H $ and arrives at an open set in $A$ that is not empty set or the full set?

Comment: @Meagain Yes, $H = [2,3]$, $A = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$ then $A \cap H$ is open and closed in $A$. But $A$ is then neither open nor closed in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your last question, the answer is: it doesn't. Suppose that $X=\mathbb R$ (with the usual topology), that $H=[0,1]$, that $A_1=(-\infty,1)$ and that $A_2=(0,+\infty)$. Then $\{A_1,A_2\}$ is an open cover of $X$, but $A_1\cap[0,1]=[0,1)$, which is *not* an open subset of $X$.

Comment: Sorry I accidently deleted the last question, let me put it back in

Comment: @Meagain I suppose that you agree with my answer to that question.

Comment: Actually there is a bit of problem. In your example H is closed in X, A_1 and A_2 forms an open cover. But in this case the statement would require H to be open.

Comment: @Meagain I don't understand your comment. At that stage of the proof, nothing is being assumed about $H$, other than the fact that $H\cap A_j$ is open in $A_j$.

Comment: But given $A_{1}, A_{2}$ as in the example, it was assumed that $H$ is a closed set in $X$. Then $ A_{1} \cap [0,1] $ was shown to be not open in $X$. What I asked is that if nothing is assumed for $H$, and $ A_{1} \cap H $ and $ A_{2} \cap H $ are open in $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ respectively, why is it that $H$ would be open in $X$. In the current case we assumed $H$ to be closed so certainly $ A_{1} \cap H $ is not open in $X$ because that was never in the claim.

Comment: @Meagain Where did I assume that $H$ is closed?

Comment: Because $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$????

Comment: @Meagain It *happens* to be closed. I did not *assume* that. And if I had chosen $H=(0,1]$, then my exemple would still works but this new $H$ is not closed.